# PrimeNG - Checkbox value as number

Tags: angular, checkbox, primeng, primeng-checkbox

I am using primeng checkbox. I am trying to add number to the 'value' property of p-checkbox.

```
<p-checkbox value={{myNumb}} [(ngModel)]="rowData.enabled"></p-checkbox>

myNumb: number = 1;
```

Even though myNumb is set to a number, and rowData.enabled is also number, once the checkbox is checked, rowData.enabled will look like this:

> enabled: ["1"]

I have also tried with the normal checkbox as:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" [(ngModel)]="rowData.enabled">
```

but in this case, it seems like that ngModel ignores the value and uses the boolean true / false.

So I get

> enabled: true

I could use any of these cases, as long as I get

> enabled: 1

**EDIT:** I changed value to [value] and now I'm getting number, but it's in array

> enabled: [1]

Is this the default behaviour of  ? That it stores the values in arrays

Answer (score 1):

try `<p-checkbox [value]="myNumb" [(ngModel)]="rowData.enabled"></p-checkbox>`

Comment: This will just parse myNumb as a string.

Comment: read the [document](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/checkbox) and try add `binary` to true

Comment: if its not work when added the binary, you can warpper `p-checkbox` component to a new component and translate the value in your new component. good luck.